# Counterexample for the continuity of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone show me a counterexample to the following statement?
If $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is derivable on $E \subset \mathbb R$ and $f':E \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is its derivative, then $f'$ is continuous on all the points of $E$.
Thank you

Comment: With $E = \mathbb{R}$, try $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ with the value $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see. f is derivable because the limit of the incremental ratio goes to 0 for x->0 both from right and left; but for x=/=0 the derivative is (x+1)/sin(1/x) which does not go to 0 as we would expect from the previous calculation of the incremental ratio. That's right?

Comment: I would work out the fact that $f'(0)$ exists using the definition of derivative, but that's the right idea.  I'd also recommend posting your own answer with all the details.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: $f(t):=\int_{[0,t]} [x]dx$ for $t> 1$.